# ASP.NET: Repeater does not work for me

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

My C# Code

```
public partial class Message : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String strconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        members();
    }

    public void members()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconn);
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            string str = "Select Users.Username,Users.Name,ProfilePic.Pathh From Users FULL OUTER JOIN ProfilePic ON Users.username = ProfilePic.Username ORDER BY Users.Sno";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str,con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            repMembers.DataSource = ds;
            repMembers.DataBind();
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            lbMembers.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And My HTML Code

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="repMembers" runat="server" >
                           <asp:ItemTemplate >
                               <div style="width:100%; border-bottom:#ffffff 2px solid;"> <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Pathh") %>' width="60px" Height="60px"/>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lb" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>'></asp:Label><br/><asp:Label ID="lbname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label><br/></div>
                           </asp:ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

My Table is absolutely correct and is working, i checked it with Grid View. It gives me the "Name","Username", and "Path" Stored.
I checked it with SQL query and displayed it in grid view.

[This is the Photo of my table,it is the combination of two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L2T3.jpg)

Comment: Aside from your issue, there is so much wrong with this code - lack of using statement or correct closing/dispose of connection, hardcoded sql, poor naming, tightly coupled your UI page to your data logic..

Comment: There's also a lot wrong with the above comment.

Comment: @DavidB while he's not answering the question per se, there's nothing wrong with pointing out other possible issues with the code.

Comment: true enough, I commented before the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ItemTemplate` instead of `asp:ItemTemplate`. There's also a typo with the word "Pathh", does this solve your issue?

```
<ItemTemplate >
    <div style="width:100%; border-bottom:#ffffff 2px solid;">
        <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Path") %>' width="60px" Height="60px"/>
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lb" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
        <br/>
        <asp:Label ID="lbname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
        <br/>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank You, It worked. I used <ItemTemplate> instead of <asp:Itemtemplate>